# Replacing array with another array but same name

Tags: actionscript-3

How do I replace an array or define it and then give it values based off a users choice? The code with the if statements below are some choices I need in one or both arrays.

For example

```
if(choice=="easy")
{
var sorted:Array = new Array("Beau","Dad","Jesus","Mary","Mom");
}
if(choice=="hard")
{
var sorted:Array = new Array("Beau","Dad","Jesus","Mary","Mom","Jordyn","Presley","Daddy","Mommy","Grandma","Grandpa","Nana","Gepa");
}
```

But this doesn't work above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the variable outside the condition instead (I also changed `if/if` to `if/elseif` as `choice` can't be *both* `easy` and `hard` at the same time):

```
var sorted:Array;

if(choice=="easy")
{
    sorted = new Array("Beau","Dad","Jesus","Mary","Mom");
} else if(choice=="hard")
{
    sorted = new Array("Beau","Dad","Jesus","Mary","Mom","Jordyn","Presley","Daddy","Mommy","Grandma","Grandpa","Nana","Gepa");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an additional option to h2oooooo' answer , you can use something like:

```
    var sorted:Array = {    
              "easy":["Beau","Dad","Jesus","Mary","Mom"],
              "medium":["Jordyn","Presley","Jesus","Mary","Nana"],
              "hard":["Beau","Dad","Jesus","Mary","Mom","Jordyn","Presley",
                      "Daddy","Mommy","Grandma","Grandpa","Nana","Gepa"]
               }[choice];

    trace(sorted.constructor); // [class Array]
```

Comment: @h2ooooooo , for sceptics i attached a `constructor`' trace ;)

Comment: Ah, ignore my previous comment if you saw it - I just thought it was odd creating an object, but assigning it to an `Array` as I missed the `[choice]` part :)